# How can I reduce the stress score from a Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) analysis?

Tags: scikit-learn, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have a precomputed distance matrix that I have run through Sklearn's MDS algorithm.  All data are needed.  The matrix has been scaled (0-1).  I am looking to convert the analysis into a plot so the max n_components = 3.

I've tried to modify several parameters (n_components, random_state, n_init), however, I am unable to reduce the stress - 1 (normalized) value below 0.25, which is considered a 'poor' fit.

When I increase the n_components really high (n_components = 100), the stress score drops to 0.01.  Would I be able to take these 100 dimensions and reduce them using PCA perhaps?

Any suggestions on how to improve the fit?  Should I try a different tool instead?

Here is the code:

#Pre-computed distance matrix

df = pd.read_excel('./FTM_fingerprint_FULL_dissimilarity_matrix_MORGAN_1024_2.xlsx', index_col = 0, header = 0)

#Multidimensional scaling

mds1 = MDS(random_state = 1, dissimilarity = 'precomputed', n_init=16, n_components=3, eps=1e-9)

X_transform = mds1.fit_transform(df)

print(X_transform)

#normalized stress score

stress = mds1.stress_

print(stress)

Thanks

Comment: can you share how the data looks like and the code you have? I would guess you need to scale the data (if you haven't) or remove some non-informative columns

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf.  Thanks for the reply.  Here is the code:

Comment: Hi @prfsullivan, thanks for the info. Please edit your question to include this information. Don't use the answer option

Comment: Ok modified the original question entry.  Thanks for letting me know @StupidWolf